# presto docker containers on production environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, presto, trino

we intend to build presto cluster on docker containers

we have ***12 RHEL machines*** ,

the simple implementation is to set presto service on docker container per Linux machine

on the other-hand we are thinking about the following different plan and we will appreciate to get feedback's about this plan

since we have 12 physical Linux machines

we can build 4 docker containers on each Linux machine

when each docker container will include presto service

so total presto workers will be  `4 X 12 = 48`

Comment: please read my post again !! , I am asking if we can set presto containers on one machine ( especially when each container include presto worker unique name )

Comment: I see a conflicts with your note - you say I can do what I want - means to set couple of presto docker containers on one machine , but you also said you not sure if this will works ? so what I need to understand from your note ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the question is: should I run one Presto worker per machine or multiple?

In general: one Presto worker per machine will perform much better than multiple workers.

There are some edge cases though. If your machines have more than 200 GB memory, you may get some performance penalty from JVM due to rather large heap sizes. (This, however, requires more thought, so don't take it as an advice to run multiple workers per machine.)

Make sure you run on Java 11 or newer. This is in fact one of the main reasons why [Presto requires Java 11 starting with Presto 333](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-333.html#server-changes).

Note: you do not need to build your own Docker image. We publish a Centos-based image at https://hub.docker.com/r/prestosql/presto. Hope this is helpful.